# Match two patterns on one line and print them in two columns

Tags: awk, filter, grep

I have about few hundred CSV files. These CSV files have different definitions and I don't want to manually unite all the CSV files into one format.

I want to get two different things from the files - A and B, and I can match both of them with regex. I want to match both of them at once - so only rows with both things will be printed. I know how to do that, and I've seen many SO posts answering how to do it.

But I don't know how to print just `A B` without rest of the line. I don't know in which order or in which columns will be the two things, so I don't know how (or if I even can) use awk.

Example:

(match A[0-9], B[0-9])

```
A0 B0 C0
B1 C1 D1
E2 C2 A2
C3 F3 F3
B4 F4 A4
```

Result:

```
A0 B0
A4 B4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** using `match` function of `awk`. It will give output in order from letter A to B as per OP's shown examples.

```
awk '
match($0,/A[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(val && match($0,/B[0-9]+/)){
     print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd Solution:*** This solution will not care of letter A and B, so in which order they are coming into line they will appear in same order.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /A[0-9]+/ || $i ~ /B[0-9]+/){
       val=val?val OFS $i:$i
    }
  }
  if(val ~ /A[0-9]+/ && val ~ /B[0-9]+/){
    print val
  }
  val=""
}
END{
  if(val ~ /A[0-9]+/ && val ~ /B[0-9]+/){
    print val
  }
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd Solution:*** considering that you need them in order of A to B in output then following may help.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     line=$i
     sub(/[0-9]+/,"",line)
     if($i ~ /A[0-9]+/ || $i ~ /B[0-9]+/){
       array[tolower(line)]=$i
     }
  }
  if(array["a"] ~ /A[0-9]+/ && array["b"] ~ /B[0-9]+/){
     print array["a"],array["b"]
  }
  delete array
}
END{
  if(array["a"] ~ /A[0-9]+/ && array["b"] ~ /B[0-9]+/){
     print array["a"],array["b"]
  }
}'   Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Adding information from `man awk` documentation about used functions eg--> `match`, `tolower`, `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`

> match(s, r [, a])       Returns the position in s where the regular
>   expression r occurs, or 0 if r is not present, and sets the values of
>   RSTART
>                           and RLENGTH.  Note that the argument order is the same as for the ~ operator: str ~ re.  If array a is  provided,  a
>   is
>                           cleared  and  then  elements  1  through  n are filled with the portions of s that match the corresponding
>   parenthesized
>                           subexpression in r.  The 0’th element of a contains the portion of s matched by the entire regular expression  r.
>   Sub-
>                           scripts  a[n,  "start"],  and  a[n,  "length"] provide the starting index in the string and length respectively, of
>   each
>                           matching substring.
>
> RSTART      The index of the first character matched by match(); 0 if
>   no match.  (This implies that character indices start at one.)
>
> RLENGTH
>   The length of the string matched by match(); -1 if no match.
>
> tolower(str)            Returns a copy of the string str, with all the
>   upper-case characters in str translated to their corresponding
>   lower-case
>                                  counterparts.  Non-alphabetic characters are left unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to print just A B without rest of the line.

Well, you need to remove everything but A and B from matching lines and force awk to recompute fields (`$1=$1` does that).

```
awk '/A[0-9]/ && /B[0-9]/ { gsub(/[^AB][0-9]/,""); $1=$1; print }' file
```